# CSS multicolumn layout: <li> cut in half when uneven amount of users online

Tags: html, css, sass

So I'm trying out a new chat room and I wanted to display a list of users into two columns. When I have two people in the room the `<li>`'s get nicely spread across the two columns. However, when there is an uneven amount of li's I get the below problem. Can someone take a look at my code and see what I did wrong?

edit: I deleted the column-fill: balance, but still nothing.

[image]

**SCSS code**

```
.first-main-column {
    .first-column-window {
      height: 700px;
      background-color: #ffffff;
      .user-container {
        height: 350px;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
        columns: 2;
        column-gap: 1em;
        column-rule: thin solid black;
        h2 {
          font-family: "Bebas Neue";
          column-span: all
        }
        .list {
          column-fill: balance;
          ul {
            li {
              width: 80%;
              border-radius: 5px;
              margin: 0 auto;
            }
          }
        }
      }

      .btn-container{
        width: 100%;
        height: 350px;
        button {
          margin: 5% 0;
          padding: 5%;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

**HTML code**

```
<div class="col-md-4 first-main-column">
        <div class="first-column-window w-80">
            <div class="user-container">
                <h2 class="p-2">User List</h2>
                <div class="list">
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item my-2" *ngFor="let user of userList">
                            {{user}}
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-container ">
                <button class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary" (click)="joinRoom('general', chatWindow)">General Chat</button>
                <!-- House chat should be different with each house-->
                <button class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-warning" (click)="joinRoom('house', chatWindow)">House Chat</button>
                <button class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-danger" (click)="joinRoom('country', chatWindow)">Country Chat</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You really should add a JSFidlle so i could test my argument. But I think your `column-fill` property on `.user-container .list` is wrong.

See the [column-list documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-fill)

Comment: If you want the _list_ in two columns, then apply the property to the _list_ ... and not the container element, that also contains a headline ...

Comment: CBroe, I already tried that, but then it doesn't even show columns.

Comment: I can't tell without a fiddle, but maybe.. make your h2  outside the column div and display block so it is full width?

Comment: It would be better if you add a fiddle here, without that its hard to tell. I think you can try by adding a fixed `height` to `li.list-group-item`, then it would always have a fixed height, no matter what.

Comment: Have you tried what is written [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/break-inside/)?

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
display: inline-block;
```

to your li style.

```
.list {
    column-fill: balance;
    ul {
        li {
            width: 80%;
            border-radius: 5px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            display: inline-block;
        }
    }
}
```